# Prove that length of two line segments are equal in a circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

> In the figure, B is the center of the semi-circle, $C$, $E$ are two points on the circle, $CG$ and $EF$ is perpendicular to $AF$, $ED$ is perpendicular to $CB$, prove that $DF$ = $CG$.

How to do this question without coordinate-geometry? Thanks in advance. Hints are welcomed.

[image]

Seems that this is useful, but I don't see how:
[image]

Comment: how is $AF$ diameter here?

Comment: @DevanshKamra The line passes through the origin

Comment: Odd.  The perpendicular to CB passing through D intersects the circle in two locations, not one.  Do we know anything about how one of these two points is selected?  It seems important since only one of the two intersection points seems to have the property implied by the picture.

Comment: @JakeMirra this is because of my problem. It is actually a semi-circle with only the upper  half part

Comment: @LearningMathematics Did you forget to mention that D must be chosen so that EFA is a right angle?  The picture implies it, but nothing in your textual description implies it.

Comment: @Jake I am sorry, I have updated the question, sorry for the ambiguity, please check.

Comment: I have added a "hint" I found on the Internet, how is it useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be the radius of the semicircle.

In right triangle $CGB$, $ \frac{ CG} { BG} = \sin \angle CBG$.

EDBF is a cyclic quad, so by extended sine rule, $\frac{ DF}{ \sin \angle DBF } = R$.

Thus, $ DF = R \sin \angle DBF = R \sin \angle CBG = CG$.

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometric Solution

$\sin \angle COD=\frac {CD}{R}$

$\sin \angle COD=\sin \angle (180-COD)=\sin \angle COF$

${\frac{GF}{\sin \angle COF}=\frac{OF}{\sin \angle COF}}$

$\angle FGO=\sin \angle OEF$ (same segments)

$\sin \angle OEF=\sin \angle FGO=\frac {OF}{R}$

${\frac{GF}{\sin \angle COF}=\frac{OF}{\frac{OF}{R}}}=R$

$\sin \angle COF = \frac {GF}{R}$

$\sin \angle COD=\frac {CD}{R}  = \frac {GF}{R}  =\sin \angle COF$

$CD=GF$

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this in case anyone is interested in a proof that doesn't use the cyclic quad machinery.

One can see that $ \angle FEG = \angle COA $ since one is a $ 90^o $ rotation of the other.  Let $ \alpha = \angle FEG = \angle COA $ and $ \beta = \angle AOE $.  One can deduce (by applying the definition of sine and cosine to triangle $ OGE $) that $ |OG| = r\cos(\beta - \alpha) $ and $ |GF| = r\sin(\beta - \alpha) $, where $ r $ is the radius of the circle.

Now consider triangle $ FEG $.  Applying the law of cosines to this triangle, we have
$$
|EG|^2 = |FG|^2 + |FE|^2 - 2 |FG||FE|\cos(\angle EFG)
$$
Now, by direct computation we find that
$$
|EG|^2 = r^2 \sin^2(\alpha)
$$
which is the same as $ |CD|^2 $.